# ReactJS dropdown menu not working backdrop-filter

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I'm trying to add blur backdrop filter to my dropdown menu in react js project.
But it's not work. It's work with all anothher elements but not working with this.

I mean I need blur like in header in dropdown menu.
[Here image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZLYl.jpg)

I really want to bealive somebody help me with this. I try many things but it's not help me

This react code:

```
function Header(){
    return(
        <div>
            <div className="Header">
                <div className="Header-Container">
                <img className="Logo" src={Logo} />
                    <div className="search-cont"><input type="search" id="site-search" name="q" placeholder="Поиск..."></input></div>
                    <NavItem >
                        <DropdownMenu/>
                    </NavItem>
                <img id="Basket" src={Basket}/>
                <img id="Profile" src={Profile}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

function NavItem(props){
    const[open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    return(
        <div className="Category">
            <div onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
                Все категории
                <img id="DownArrow" src={DownArrow}/>
            </div>

            {open && props.children}
        </div>
);
}
function DropdownMenu(){
    function DropdownItem(props){
        return(
        <div className="menu-item">
            {props.children}
        </div>
        );
    }
    return(
        <div className="dropdown">
            <DropdownItem>
                #Хиты
            </DropdownItem>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This SCSS code:

```
body{
  .Header {
    .dropdown{
      backdrop-filter: blur(5px) opacity(100%);
      background: #333333a5 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
      display: inline-block;
      box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 35px #c8c8c810, 0px 3px 30px #0000004D;
      border: 1px solid #666666a8;
      border-radius: 15px;
      z-index: 10;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0vh;
      padding-top: 40%;
      padding-left: 20%;
      padding-right: 20%;
      padding-bottom: 40%;
      opacity: 1;
      .menu-item{
        height: 2vw;
        width: 12vw;
        margin-bottom: 5%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        border-radius: 10px;
        transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
        text-align: center;
        font: normal normal bold 18px Montserrat;
        letter-spacing: 1.2px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        opacity: 1;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      .menu-item:hover {
        background-color: #FFFFFF28;
      }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Never declare a React Component inside another React Component, since it's going to be destroyed and recreated at each render.

> ```
> function DropdownItem(props){
>                     return(
>                     <div className="menu-item">
>                         {props.children}
>                     </div>
>                     );
>                 }
>
> function DropdownMenu(){
>             return(
>                 <div className="dropdown">
>                     <DropdownItem>
>                         #Хиты
>                     </DropdownItem>
>                 </div>
>             );
>         }
> ```

- I tried your code on stackblitz and it seems to work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-onrm6s?file=src%2FApp.js

Make sure you have updated your browser since backdrop-filter is not supported by all browsers.

Comment: Thank you for you advise.

I have anothers backdrop-filter in this project and they work well.

But this one not work, acctualy I think this work not correct. I see what this blur elements in header, but effect have some transparantm, like opacity less 1. And in main page hasn't any blur effect. It's really strange

Comment: If you inspect the element does the backdrop-filter css property appear properly on the element ? Can you try to reproduce the page style on that stackblitz so we see if we reproduce the issue.

Comment: There is:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rc6hcn?file=src/index.js

Comment: I think the problem is that you are trying to use the dropdown element with backdrop-filter over another element that has backdrop-filter, for example on your stackblitz, on small screens the dropdown gets over the Banner-Glass element, by removing backdrop-filter from Banner-Glass blur works again.

Comment: OMG. Thank you. Problem didn't in Banner-Glass, but problem did Glass effect in header. I rebuild layout and now all work great.